# Error opening PDF files and change the size when copying from one PC to another

Tags: pdf, file-transfer, adobe-acrobat

I have a very strange problem.

In the office I save the PDF file to the desktop (at work I have a license of Adobe Acrobat X Pro). With the file everything is OK, no problems.

Then connect from home via Remote Desktop to the office computer and copy the file to my home PC. When I try to open a file it crashes with the error message *"There was an error opening this document. The file is damaged and could not be repaired".*

First I thought about the possible incompatibility between versions (at home I have Adobe Reader 9.5.5).

But after several attempts found that the file actually spoils, and spoils it when copying from PC to PC. The fact is that during the transfer from one computer to another PDF file is slightly increased in size. So my file in 344 KB turned into a 352 KB. And it only happens with PDF files. Others are transferred and copied normally.

PS: In my office I have Windows 7 Pro, home on the laptop - Windows XP Pro SP3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How you copy? Pack it ZIP archive and upload. If the file is damaged, it is still Repack any archiver with password, and try again to pass. 10 kb were added. Even it is interesting what exactly was added there. Didn't look? In the properties of the RDP connection check Local resources/Devices/Still/disc/Disc, E, on your choice that at you in a remote desktop appeared your disk(s). Maybe so won't damage.

Comment: This is a workaround but doesn't explain the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely your copying process changes the end-of-line conventions. Your PDF may use a simple `LF` (*line feed*, 1 Byte) as is common on Linux, Unix and Mac OS X. Windows however uses `CR+LF` (*carriage return* plus *line feed*, 2 Bytes).

Are you, by any chance, using FTP for the remote file transfer? In that case you should switch on the *"binary"* mode. This will then not touch and change the existing EOL characters. Better still, try to use WinSCP.

If you compress your PDF first with WinZip or similar, it may happen that your FTP client automatically switches to binary mode (in case you don't know how to do that.)

Comment: He clearly says he uses Remote Desktop to copy the files.

Comment: Whatever he says... Maybe "policy" has forbidden to transfer files. So he is "clever" and opens file in text editor and copy'n'pastes. Been there, done that...

Comment: We can't go around simply assuming that he's lying. If he says he's using RDP then that's what answers have to be based upon. If you doubt him then ask for clarification.

Comment: @Karan: C'mon, get reasonable again. No-one said he's lying. And asking for clarification I was. Also repeated in the answer *"Are you, by any chance, ..."*

Comment: Your "whatever he says" comment above that suggests he's copy-pasting the PDFs as text seems to clearly throw doubt on his statement that he copied the files via RDP. As for using FTP, I don't see why anyone would do that from within an already established RDP connection, unless again you're doubting that he's using RDP. Anyway, this cannot be resolved conclusively without the OP responding.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to right-click on the file and select "Properties". Then check if the **Properties** dialog displays *"This file came from another computer and might be blocked to help protect this computer"* message. If it is displayed then click on **Unblock** button and then check if this PDF opens again